# I cannot see or render an image as the world background in cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, world

When I set the background to an option from blender it works fine but I wont work when I select an image from my computer.

In the screenshot I have an image selected but its just coming up as one solid colour as shown

[image]

Comment: The world should have an image that uses equirectangular projection. What does your image and world node setup look like? I suspect you are trying to use a flat image which does not work with the default setup.

Comment: yeah its a flat image. Do i need to convert it to a hdri?

Answer (score 2):

To use a flat image, (really not recommended, you don't gain any dynamic range or depth of the environment) you will need to use an [*image texture* node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/textures/image.html#image-texture-node) rather than an [*environment texture* node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/textures/environment.html#environment-texture-node) and set the [*texture coordinate*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/texture_coordinate.html#texture-coordinate-node) node to *window* so that the image fits within the camera bounds at all times.

There is a significant drawback to this, in that using an image this way does not provide the lighting that an HDRI does provide, and therefore it is better to use an actual HDRI that contains the lighting information and that captured the correct equirectangular projection that the environment image should have. See the gifs below for an example of the differences.

---

Regular photo, it contains no real light information, uses *window coordinates* stays static while the camera rotates:

[image]

HDRI with light information, correct projection as would be expected of the world when camera is moved:

[image]

---

Either of those two options will solve your current dilemma, if you do not have any HDRI images, there are plenty of resources for free ones, see our *[Resources for Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender) post* here for some good ones.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not using an image as environment, meaning that the image is not  HDR in equirectangular projection and you are not using it to light the scene, but just want it as background. Then set the image's vector to **Window**

[image]